# Toggle text color when button is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array of buttons with text on top of each. These buttons were created in the library and imported to the stage using as3. When I click on each button the text turns green. I want to change the color back to black when I click on another button in the array. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have independent buttons, so you need some logic to make other buttons get turned to black. You can either centralize button management in their common parent, or make each button know about every other button so they can tell others to turn black when they get clicked.

Comment: How  do I code that in as3? I'm sorry. I'm a newbie at this.